# Is Philemon necessary?

Tags: philemon

Is there anything proven in Philemon? Is anything actually useful? Is anything taught about getting closer to Jesus?

I have not found anything useful in that book, but there might be something in there.

Comment: Related:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/328/is-paul-suggesting-that-philemon-release-onesimus-from-slavery?rq=1

Comment: @Ruminator Can any principles be pulled out and applied to our own lives?

Comment: The letter is ostensibly written to a single man, that owned slave(s), in the first century, just before the Great Jewish Revolt c. 63-67 AD/CE. Like the letters of Lincoln, people derive things from it anyway. Paul's letter suggests a win-win situation, Paul gets the services of Onesimus at a discount, Philemon gets a heavenly reward for gifting Onesimus' service, and Onesimus gets a heavenly reward for his services.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Which passage of scripture would we use to arrive at a conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necessary? No. But informative and edifying... yes. And 'yes' also to useful. Among the important teachings in this letter are:

- The idea that a slave is a beloved brother in Christ.
- The idea that a runaway slave should not be punished but welcomed back.
- The absolute value of Onesimus as a person rather than property.

In addition, the letter, by giving us the name Onesimus, opens the possibility that this person went on to become a the [Bishop of Ephesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onesimus). This is not proven, but such a bishop is mentioned by Ignatius of Antioch. Either way, the letter shows the remarkable attitude of the early church toward eliminating distinctions of social class. Onesimus the slave is now remembered as a saint and even an apostle in various church traditions.

[image]

Since this answer is penned during the Christmas season, I will close with a quote from a beloved hymn, *O Holy Night*, which pertains to this topic:

```
Truly He taught us to love one another
His law is love and His Gospel is Peace
Chains shall He break, for the slave is our brother
And in His name, all oppression shall cease
```

It took far too long for the church to put this teaching into practice fully. However, by presenting Onesimus as “a brother, beloved…to me, but even more so to you” (v 16), Paul expressed a revolutionary idea in his day.

Answer (score 4):

The great apostle, Paul, is often castigated by some, who believed (incorrectly) that he was in favor of perpetuating slavery, largely based on his comments in places like Eph 6:5 -

> Slaves, obey your earthly masters with respect and fear and sincerity
> of heart, just as you would obey Christ.

However, this was only half of Paul's attitude to the institution of slavery.  The letter to Philemon clearly shows the other half as demonstrated in V13-17

> **13** I would have liked to keep him with me, so that on your behalf he could minister to me in my chains for the gospel. **14** But I did
> not want to do anything without your consent, so that your goodness
> will not be out of compulsion, but by your own free will. **15** For
> perhaps this is why he was separated from you for a while, so that you
> might have him back for good— **16** **no longer as a slave, but
> better than a slave, as a beloved brother**. He is especially beloved
> to me, but even more so to you, both in person and in the Lord.
>
> **17** So if you consider me a partner, receive him as you would receive me.

Thus, Paul's attitude to slavery (and by extension, the Christian Church) becomes evident:

1. Slaves should obey their masters
2. Masters should treat slaves as brothers in Christ

It was precisely this policy that eventually resulted in laying the foundation for Christian reformers like William Wilberforce and William Pit, to eliminate slavery.

In this sense, Paul's letter to Philemon is one of the most valuable social reform documents in the NT.

Paul's appeal to Philemon appears to have resulted in Onesimus becoming a "fellow-worker" with Paul and his missionary endeavors because read in Col 4:9 -

> with Onesimus, the faithful and beloved brother, who is one of you
> [ministers of the Gospel, see V7]. They will make known to you all
> things here.

Thus, Paul, used the "Love of Christ" as powerful weapon that ultimately outlawed slavery, at least among Christians and those place where they had influence.